# Regular expression help - what's wrong?

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to ask for help with my regex. I need to extract the very last part from each URL. I marked it as 'to_extract' within the example below.

I want to know what's wrong with the following regex when used with sed:

```
sed 's/^[ht|f]tp.*\///' file.txt
```

Sample content of file.txt:

```
http://a/b/c/to_extract
ftp://a/b/c/to_extract
...
```

I am getting only correct results for the ftp links, not for the http.
Thanks in advance for your explanation on this.
i.

Answer (score 8):

Change `[ht|f]` to `(ht|f)`, that would give better results.

`[abc]` means "one character which is `a`, `b` or `c`".

`[ht|f]` means "one character which is `h`, `t`, `|` or `f`", not at all what you want.

On some versions of sed, you'll have to call it with the `-r` option so that extended regex can be used :

```
sed -r 's/^(ht|f)tp.*\///' file.txt
```

If you just want to extract the last part of the url and don't want anything else, you probably want

```
sed -rn 's/^(ht|f)tp.*\///p' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 just for info, works on GNU sed, not posix version taht does not allow `|`

Comment: Without `-r` you need to backslash the parentheses and the pipe character in many `sed` dialects.  You should find that `sed '/\(ht\|f\)tp/'` works with GNU `sed` as well.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for that information (I still keep my answer as is because I think it's more readable and convenient to use the r parameter)

Comment: Note that the -r parameter is only supported by GNU sed. The more convenient and portable way is to escape parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

How about use "basename" :

```
basename http://a/b/c/to_extract    
to_extract
```

you can simply achieve what you want with a for loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

myarr=( $(cat ooo) )

for i in ${myarr[@]}; do

basename $i

done
```

Comment: Why write a loop when you can use sed ? And how do you deal with lines *not* containing any url ?

Comment: @dystroy sure, I think sed is 1st priority that everyone wanna use, I just wanna say there is another way can deal with general cases without regex, but anyway, you're right